# Crystal Report Page Footer is not Printing

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

Using VB.Net 2012 and Crystal Reports

Section page footer is not printing on the bottom of the page.

I have the page size set to envelope monarch I am printing on an envelope.

I know my setting have to be correct.

I updated from a previous crystal report made in vb.net 2003 that worked fine.

I measured the envelope and no print should be off of the envelope. 
The section is not suppressed or containing blank information.

Comment: You should review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to go into the print options and check no printer and dissociate printer papersize.